# In oracle SQL , how to count the no of records based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with below structure :

```
Col2
A
A
B
B
E
E
```

I wanted the SQL query to output me the following :

```
Internal    4
External    2
Total   6
```

Logic : If the values in the Col2 are A,B then it should be summed up as Internal , If E then it should be summed up as External.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map your column values use [DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE),  simple providing the list of the original and new values for the column.

```
select decode(col2,'A','Internal','B','Internal','E','External') col from tab
```

To calculate the total you do not need to rescan the whole table (performance drops to the half) but use  [group by rollup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-aggregation-data-warehouses.html#GUID-01BBD582-E149-47D7-A4F8-F50C1AAC66AA)  that calculates the *Total*

```
with t as ( 
select decode(col2,'A','Internal','B','Internal','E','External') col from tab)
select nvl(col,'Total') col, count(*) cnt
from t
group by rollup (col)
```

Result

```
COL             CNT
-------- ----------
External          2
Internal          4
Total             6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when col2 in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as internal,
       sum(case when col2 = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as external,
       count(col2) as total
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'Internal' "summed up as"
       ,sum(case when Col2 in ('A', 'B') then 1
            else 0
            end) "sum"
from test
union
select 'External' "summed up as"
       ,sum(case when Col2 = 'E' then 1
            else 0
            end) "sum"
from test
union
select 'Total' "summed up as"
       , count(Col2) "sum"
from test;
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72f42576504d10cc99ef3f44552807df)

Answer (score 1):

try like below using union all and make customize group

```
   select case when col2 in ('A','B') then 'Internal' else 'External' end,
    count(*) as result
   from table_name
   group by case when col2 in ('A','B') then 'Internal' else 'External' end
   union all
  select 'total', count(*) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Col2Count) as Internal from (SELECT Col2 as Col2, count( Col2 ) as Col2Count
FROM tablename group by Col2) where Col2 in (A,B);
```

This will give you result as :

Internal
4